# How to travel reverse diagonally through a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have been trying to solve the problem in C.
I can travel through my 2D array diagonally with this code:

```
    for(int k = 0; k<10*2; k++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<=k; j++) {
        int i = k-j;
        if (i <10 && j<10) {
            printf("%d ", tomb[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

So if my 2D array (tomb) is:

```
0  1  2  3  4

5  6  7  8  9

10 11 12 13 14

15 16 17 18 19

20 21 22 23 24
```

Then my output for diagonal ( / shape):

```
0

5 1

10 6  2

15 11 7  3

20 16 12 8 4

21 17 13 9

22 18 14

23 19

24
```

My questions is, how I could travel through this array in reverse diagonal ( \ shape), so that my output would look like this:

```
4

3 9

2 8 14

1 7 13 19

0 6 12 18 24

5 11 17 23

10 16 22

15 21

20
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `tomb` and how it is filled with data.

Comment: *`if (i <10 && j<10) { printf("%d ", tomb[i][j]); }`* – `<10` doesn't make sense for the input you provided which is 5 x 5.

Comment: Agreed - the example code is a little strange - why `k<=10*2`? Why not simply `k<20`...but why 20 at all? it's a 5x5 2-d array...20 doesn't figure into it anywhere I can see.

Comment: That code works. That gives me the numbers diagonally ( / shape)
My problem is, that, I would like to go around the other way ( \ shape)

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: Your example (5x5 array) does not fit your code, which has a lot of confusing constants in it, such as 2*10 and the like.  Along the same lines, using variable names like i, k and j doesn't help with readability (for both yourself and others).  I highly recommend using proper variable names like row, width, column, height, "diagonal" and so forth.

Comment: I just ran your code in a test and did not get the output you are posting.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the square matrix of dimension = size x size here is the code

```
       for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            int j = size - i - 1;
            for(int k = 0; k <= i; ++k,++j) {
                printf("%d ",tomb[k][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
            int j = 0;
            for(int k = i; k < size ; k++, j++) {
                printf("%d ", tomb[k][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

Whole code demo
https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/fq59Cm8Hqt Only the code is in Java

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. The answer is:

```
for(int k = -5; k<=5; k++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<5; j++) {
        if ((j-k>=0) &&(j-k<5)) {
            printf("%d ", tomb[j][j-k]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```